# Efficient way to pass arrays in url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am building a webapp and have a few arrays that I would like to pass through the URL in order to make the results of my application easily sharable.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I know a lot of websites (like youtube) use some sort of encoding to make their URLs shorter, would that be an option here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the size of the array?

Comment: Have you read any of the 3+million results "Efficient way to pass arrays in url" receives on Google?

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to create short URLs like YouTube (ex. youtube.com/xYjfl293) or do you want to pass data via JSON, or via the query string?

Comment: i like escaped JSON better than GET params for this very reason, Arrays are far less repetitive.

Comment: I have read the google results and most of them deal with PHP, I am just trying to pass a javascript array back to the URL. 
There are 4 arrays of doubles that come from graphs that the user can alter on my page. I would like those arrays to be passable by URL so that the user does not have to alter the control graphs again. rahulmehta got what I was asking, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect you're asking is you have some page where the user can alter information, etc, and you want a way to create a URL on the fly with that information so it can easily be accessed again. I've listed two approaches here:

1. Use the query string. On your page you can have a button saying "save" that produces a URL with info about what the user did. For example, if I have a webpage where all I do is put my name in and select a color, I can encode that as `http://my-website.com/page?name=John_Doe&color=red`. Then, if I visit that link, your page could access the query object in JavaScript and load a page with the `name` and `color` field already set.
2. An approach for the "YouTube-style" URLs would be to create a hash of the relevant information corresponding to the page. For example, if I were creating a service for users to store plaintext files. These files are to have the following attributes: `title, date, name, and body`. We can create a hash of the string `hash_string = someHashFunction(title+date+name)`.

Of course, this is a very naive hashing scheme, but something like this may be what you are looking for. Following this, your URL would be something like `http://my-website.com/hash_string`. The key here is not only creating these URLs, but having a means to route requests on the server side to the page corresponding to the `hash_string`.

Comment: Ah, I think the second approach is what I am looking for. I should have made it clear that I know how to pass variable by URL, but I did not want the URL to look something like http://home.com?array1%3D%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%26array2%3D%5B2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C1%5D%26array3 and instead have it as a neat string, like you suggested above.
How would I go about routing these requests to the server side if I used the hash_string?

Comment: Please be aware that the length of the url can be restricted by the browser or server.